# MATLAB: Easiest way to print 1.0e-01 as 0.1 to txt

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, what is the easiest way to print
`1.0e-01` as
`0.1`
to txt file.

`1.0e-01` may not be exactly equal to `0.1` however. So there are two cases:

1. `1.0e-01` is exactly equal to `0.1`.

and

2. `1.0e-01` is not exactly equal to `0.1`.

What is the easiest way for each case?

Template for case 1:

```
x = 1.0e-01; %I cannot type it as 0.1 manually. x is an output from other function
txt1 = sprintf('testing');
fid1 = fopen(txt1,'w');
fprintf(fid1,'%.1d\n',x);   
fclose(fid1);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @beaker updated. `x` is some output from function and it is shown as `1.0e-01`.

Comment: @beaker it is also shown as `1.0e-01` by `fprintf(fid1,'%.1d\n',x)`;

Comment: @beaker I found the answer: changing to `fprintf(fid1,'%.1f\n',x)` works for me.

Comment: Yes, a float specification would be better than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do is to change `digits` and print with `vpa`(Variable precision arithmetic). For example,

```
digits(2)
vpa(0.100000000000001) %prints 0.1
```

Alternatively, you can simply use

```
vpa(0.100000000000001, 2);
```

But these prints only two digits, you need to be careful if you are using big numbers.

Comment: sorry. I cannot type `0.100000000000001` myself. `x` is an output from some other function and it is of the form of `1.0e-01`

Comment: Okay, `x = output_of_other_function(...)`. `vpa(x,2)` will also work

Comment: I found the answer: changing to `fprintf(fid1,'%.1f\n',x)` works for me.

Comment: Is vpa not working? Or did you expect me to  find exactly what you wanted?

Comment: i think vpa also works for print to screen. but surprising i found changing to `fprintf(fid1,'%.1f\n',x)` works also.

Comment: @smttsp VPA is kind of overkill for simple formatting like this, isn't it?